# Is it possible to use wildcards in Jar File names in the Policy file?

Tags: java, security, javapolicy

Is it possible to replace code like:

```
grant codeBase "file:${home.url}/installed/Engine/lib/runtime_3.jar" {

   // permission for the Engine
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "write";
};
```

With code like this:

```
grant codeBase "file:${home.url}/installed/Engine/lib/runtime_*.jar" {

   // permission for the Engine
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "write";
};
```

So as to avoid repeatedly changing the policy file with new versions of libraries?

I've not seen this documented anywhere (and am having a hard time verifying this).

Comment: By the time of deployment the Jars will need to be digitally signed, so I cannot see the point of ever touching the policy files,  You might as well work out how to digitally sign them during development.

Comment: I want to be able to do this as well. I have all my 3rd party .jar files in the same folder and want to grant specific permissions to a group of them (I have 7 spring .jars to which I want to grant the same permissions for example). Using a wildcard of "spring-*" would be very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can replace it with this:

```
grant codeBase "file:${home.url}/installed/Engine/lib/*" {
```

or this:

```
grant codeBase "file:${home.url}/installed/Engine/lib/-" {
```

Rather surprised you didn't find this in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) during your extensive research:

> A codeBase with a trailing "/*" matches all files (both class and JAR files) contained in that directory. A codeBase with a trailing "/-" matches all files (both class and JAR files) in the directory and recursively all files in subdirectories contained in that directory.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to grant permissions to all jars in the directory, just a specific one that gets upgraded every so often.